# Word boundaries with dot sign in string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match different abbreviations for the german word "Straße" (e.g. "Str" or "Str.")

How can i escape the dot sign within the string?

```
\b(Str|Str.)\b
```

And how can i setup case-insensitive? It would be nice if the regex matches "str", "sTr", ... too.

Comment: which language are you using!..a regex Q **must** be tagged with language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escape special characters with `\`.

```
\b(Str|Str\.)\b
```

Also, `?` makes the preceding token optional, so we can condense to:

```
\b(Str\.?)\b
```

Finally, case insensitivity is specified with the `i` modifier. How you specify modifiers depends on the language. In most cases they're put after the closing delimiter of the regex:

```
/\b(str\.?)\b/i
```

Comment: @Slevin: you cannot just copy-paste others' code. you need to understand what you're doing, otherwise you're going to run into `rm -rf /` one day.

Comment: Fixed my REs, they were missing the `\b` at the end.

Comment: @SilentGhost I know what the modifier are for, but they doesn't work together.  e.g. `\b(Str\.?)\b` works for me, but not with the trailing `i`. unfortunately, i know `rm -rf` ...

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can escape it by preceding it with a backslash. You can specify case insensitivity using an `i` modifier.